# Rewriting sub-domain leads to a HTTP redirect rather

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

What I'm trying to do here is rewrite my `https://demo.example.com/` sub-domain to my `https://example.com/` domain (in another folder), *without* changing the URL. However, the sub-domain keeps on redirecting me to the folder. I'm not great at HTACCESS and rewriting, but this ***should*** be an easy task to do.

This is my current HTACCESS file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^license/?(.*)$ /sites/site-licenses/$1.php [L]
RewriteRule ^portfolio/?(.*)$ /sites/site-portfolios/$1.php [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^demo\.hamiltondev\.net
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://hamiltondev.net/sites/site-demos/$1 [L,NC,QSA]
```

The first two rewrite rules is for the main domain `https://example.com/license/---` and `https://example.com/portfolio/---`.

Answer (score 0):

When a full url is used as a target in a `RewriteRule`, it automatically becomes a redirect. What you need is either use an absolute path (if demo and main domain share the same document root folder) or use a proxy request.

## both domains share document root folder

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^demo\.hamiltondev\.net$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /sites/site-demos/$1 [L,NC,QSA]
```

## otherwise, proxy

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^demo\.hamiltondev\.net$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://hamiltondev.net/sites/site-demos/$1 [P,NC,QSA]
```

Comment: Neither of the examples provided works for me, getting a 500 HTTP error. Will check what the logs says.

Comment: `AH01144: No protocol handler was valid for the URL /index.php (scheme 'https'). If you are using a DSO version of mod_proxy, make sure the proxy submodules are included in the configuration using LoadModule.`

Comment: This is an error when using second rule/possibility. You need to enable `mod_proxy`. But, reading your question again, I'm pretty sure the first solution would be fine in your case (moreover, it is also faster)